Looking for motorized shade solution for wide (64") skylight
I have a 64"w x 62"h skylight at a 50 degree angle. I removed the wood trim to replace with sheetrock, and there are 1"w x 1.5"h side channels on both sides.
There are a lot of motorized skylight options available up to about 61" width, but very little wider. Only one I've found is this product on Amazon with zero reviews.
The vendors of regular motorized window roller shades say they won't work with skylights, but is there any reason besides needing channels (which I already have)? Has anyone tried this? I can see a honeycomb might be tricky but it seems like a roller shade would work.

I don't think this question should have been closed.
